# problem while calling function from one class to another class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am creating a view based project named test,it contains testappdelegate.h,testappdelegate.m,test.h,test.m classes.

i am creating two NSObject classes named webservices.h,webservices.m

i have a method named getsource in class test.m.

now i need to call this method from webservices.m

For that i am writing the code like this.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(mymethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];

- (void)mymethod {

 MortgageCalculatorViewController *obj = [[MortgageCalculatorViewController alloc]init];
 [obj getsource];
}
```

it prints NSLog values in console,And it calls ViewDidLoad also,But there is no UIChanges.

i am trying using this

```
- (void)mymethod {

     MortgageCalculatorViewController *obj = [[MortgageCalculatorViewController alloc]init];
     [obj viewDidLoad];
    }
```

there No error but application quits.

And i am trying this in test.m class

```
[self performSelector:@selector(getsource) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
```

Then it works fine.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Hai..


What's your Exact problem..at the time of button click event you want to call the another class am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling ViewDidLoad wouldb't load the view for that class. You'd have to do `[self.view addSubView:testClassObject.view]`.

Comment: i am trying this i am getting error request for member 'view' Not a structure or union

Comment: maybe because the class from where you are calling this method doesn't have a view i.e it's not a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: If it is a NSObject subclass, it wouldn't have a view of it's own. That means while the control is in this class(suppose A), the view of the class(suppose B), that passed on the control to A is being displayed on the screen. You could try to do the addSubview after the control leaves A and enters a class with a view(can be B).